# localstorage restoring deleted data after page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I build a chat application and using `localStorage` for keep the conversation even after page refresh. If a chat end, I like to delete the `localStorage` and clear the chat window this is working fine. But If the user initiate a chat again and refresh the page than previous chat conversation restoring into the `localStorage`

Below is my code :

```
var CHAT_MSG_LOCAL = []; //store messages into it
    CHAT_MSG_LOCAL.push(msgObj); //push message into the variable

    //save in local storage  when page refreshed 
    $(window).on('unload', function () {            
        saveLocalData(CHAT_MSG_LOCAL);  
    });

    //Retrive from local storage when page load
    $(document).ready(function () {
      retriveLocalData();
      var data = retriveLocalData();
      if (data.length > 0)
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            output(data[i]); // generate html
        }
    });

    //Chat End
    $(".close-conversation").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();                
            localStorage.removeItem('local-messages');
            localStorage.setItem('local-messages', []);

        });

    //save function
    function saveLocalData(CHAT_MSG_LOCAL) {
        var messageString = JSON.stringify(CHAT_MSG_LOCAL);
        localStorage.setItem('local-messages', messageString);

    }

    //retrive function
    function retriveLocalData() {
        var localmsgObj = localStorage.getItem('local-messages');
        var retrievedObject = {};
        if (localmsgObj.length > 0) {
            retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localmsgObj);
        }
        return retrievedObject;
    }
```

please help me to find the mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing issue as above code isn't clearing CHAT_MSG_LOCAL param.

Kindly use below code to make param empty.

```
 $(".close-conversation").on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();                
      localStorage.removeItem('local-messages');
      localStorage.setItem('local-messages', []);
      CHAT_MSG_LOCAL = []; //change
  });
```

Comment: At the time of closing chat window in previous code local-messages param is empty. Then user reopen the chat so at that time as well local-param is empty, Once user refresh the browser then "Unload event" will again save the data available in CHAT_MSG_LOCAL to local storage, On page refresh data again gets populated by retriveLocalData() called in document.ready.  Thus clearing the CHAT_MSG_LOCAL = []; must have resolved our issue.    Can you please attach the exact js file.    Many Thanks

Comment: Need some fix in my code. Now its working. marked as taken answer. thanks @amit wadhwani